# Creating a new instance of an Imagebutton with a button click

Tags: java, android, mobile, dynamic, imagebutton

The app I am programming has a menu in which the user can pick a new building to build. The user will press "Buy" I would like this to create a new instance of the imagebutton that corresponds to that particular building. My current problem is that I only understand how to do this by setting up these in the xml file and setting them invisible until they buy it. I would like to dynamically create these buildings when they are bought. Is there a way to dynamically create an instance of an image button is this way? I don't really think including my source code is necessary here since I just need an example that works (most examples I have seen just don't work out). But if you would like to see some source code let me know.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Code inside buy building button:

```
newColonyHut = new ImageButton(runGraphics.this);
newColonyHut.setImageResource(R.drawable.mainhut);
newColonyHut.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
layout.addView(newColonyHut);
```

Here is the xml:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buyColonyHut"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/colonyHutPrice" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `ImageView` and dynamically add to layout you specified.

**sample:**

in `oncreate()`

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final LinearLayout test = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.test);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ImageView image = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
            image.setImageResource(your_image_here);
            image.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            test.addView(image);
        }
    });
```

the `activity_main`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/home_page"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/layer"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see `ImageView` is created when the button is clicked in the layout and then add it to the `LinearLayout` dynamically.

The `LayoutParams` is where you set the height and width of your `ImageView` respected the its parent which is the `LinearLayout`

Comment: I'll give it a shot and I will update with my results. Thank you.

Comment: When I try the setup you showed, I get a nullpointerexception pointing to the line which would be your line test.addView(image);

Comment: @saboehnke in your activity_main.xml do you have a LinearLayout that have android:id="@+id/test"??

Comment: Yes I do. Problem is that The button is inside of a relative layout that is inside of a linear layout. So I am assuming that I need to use relative layout for the layout parameters right?

Comment: @saboehnke what is layout field?

Comment: layout was just the id I was using instead of test.

Comment: @saboehnke you didnt close your RelativeLayout close it

Comment: Its just not closed in the code I posted. It is closed in the real code. I have a textview and imageview in the real code. Just forgot to close It off again when I removed them for the post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55733/discussion-between-rod-algonquin-and-saboehnke).